# Is there a way to implement a router to manage fragments on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I work developing an app that initially was created in a way that all fragments follow a linear path. From fragment A to fragment B to fragment C and so on.

As the client of the company I work for asks, we add new fragments to the app, but now it is possible that from fragment A, the path changes to fragment A1 or A2 and, each of them, can navigate to fragment B or follow its own path.

It's easier to understand by the image bellow.

[image]

Is it possible to create a "router" to manage these fragments dynamically? In a way that I create a tag to each fragment, then I set on my activity all paths and just call the path on the OnClickListener?

```
Path 1.1: A, A1, B, C
Path 1.2: A, A2, C
```

Today, every time it is asked to add another fragment between another two fragments, we must implement a series of `if` conditions on the button going forward and implementing this kind of router would simplify creating the fragment path for my application.

Comment: Just create 5 Fragments and manage them with FragmentTransaction.replace(), so what is your concern

Comment: You can check out this article: https://android.jlelse.eu/mastering-viewpager-with-directed-acyclic-graph-533ed5ee1e5e . Though, here it's shown with ViewPager. But, the concepts are the same. This is the dynamic way.

Comment: if you use fragment navigation its better to use and  good for handling fragment transaction https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/

Comment: @Inso obviously that's what I'm doing now, but what my team and I are struggling is that the paths are not that simple, there are at least 50 fragments with different paths between them and every sprint the company asks us to put other fragments and not always at the end of a path.